# Erro ao comparar duas strings

Tags: c, string, comparação, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando comparar duas *strings*, para quando eu insiro um nome na minha lista encadeada ele não poder ser inserido se já existe. Já usei a função *busca_nome* para exibir um nome pesquisado e para excluir, porém agora ela está simplesmente dando *segmentation fault* na linha que chama o `strcmp()`. Segue código para das funções referentes ao problema.

```
void insere_inicio(celula *nodo) {
    celula *teste;
    printf("\t Nome: ");
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    teste = busca_nome( nodo);
    if (teste == NULL) {
        celula *info;
        info = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
        strcpy(info->nome, busca.nome);
        printf("\t Rua: ");
        ler_string(info->rua, 40);
        printf("\t Cidade: ");
        ler_string(info->cidade, 20);
        printf("\t Estado: ");
        ler_string(info->estado, 2);
        printf("\t CEP: ");
        scanf("%lu", &info->cep);
        info -> prox = nodo -> prox;
        nodo -> prox = info;
    } else {
        printf("Esse nome já está cadastrado !!");
    }
    free(teste);
}

/*
 * função que faz a busca de um nome no programa
 * le o nome que está localizado na struct busca.nome
 * se encontra um nome igual retorna o ponteiro para o nome
 * caso não encontre retorna um ponteiro NULL
 */
celula *busca_nome(celula *inicio) {
    int flag = 0;
    celula *info;
    celula *anterior;
    do {
        if (flag == 0) {
            anterior = inicio;
            info = inicio -> prox;
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            anterior = info;
            info = info -> prox;
        }
        if (strcmp(busca.nome, info -> nome) == 0)
            return anterior;
    } while (info -> prox != NULL);

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código está cheio de problemas. Vou apontar alguns:

O principal visível é corrupção de memória. As variáveis `info` e `anterior` foram declaradas mas memória não foi alocada para elas. Quando você tentou escrever algo nelas melou a memória, possivelmente escreveu em cima de alguma coisa importante.

Também não sei de onde surgiu a variável `busca`. Ela não existe neste escopo. Existe em um escopo maior? Mesmo que exista isto não é uma prática adequada na maioria dos casos.

Esse `if` com `flag` não faz muito sentido pra mim, mas provavelmente funciona.

E na outra função você tenta liberar a memória de algo que nunca foi alocado.

Dica: sempre que possível (quase sempre é) use o `malloc()` e o `free()` que libera ele na mesma função. Usá-los separadamente é procurar confusão. Até programadores experientes se perdem quando fazem isto.

Algumas outras coisas técnicas estão estranhas mas sem ver o todo não tenho certeza. O algoritmo como um todo não parece fazer muito sentido.

Comment: corrigirei os erros apontados, o if com flag é usado por que eu tenho a primeira célula apenas como cabeça, e não uso a mesma, então para quando eu estiver percorrendo o laço na primeira vez eu tenho que pular ela e não ler a mesma...

Comment: Mas se vai executar só a primeira vez, então executa fora do `do` e inverte a ordem do `else` com o `if`de baixo. O algoritmo fica muito mais simples. Quase sempre quando tem que usar uma `flag` tem algo errado no algoritmo.